Why does kubectl get events shows nothing unlike logs?
I am trying to figure out what is wrong.
My comamand
kubectl get events --namespace kube-system  | grep -i konnectivity-agent-6688d6dbfc-rsql5
No resources found in kube-system namespace

If I opt for specific namespace
kubectl get events --all-namespaces  | grep -i kube-proxy-2pdxb

shows nothing.
Anyway pod logs are more informative
 I1127 10:47:53.070693       1 proxier.go:823] "Syncing iptables rules"
I1127 10:47:53.126287       1 proxier.go:790] "SyncProxyRules complete" elapsed="55.635032ms"
I1127 10:47:53.126314       1 bounded_frequency_runner.go:296] sync-runner: ran, next possible in 1s, periodic in 1h0m0s
I1127 10:53:51.648429       1 utils.go:180] "Skipping service due to cluster IP" service="elk/logstash-logstash-headless" clusterIP="None"
I1127 10:53:51.648462       1 utils.go:180] "Skipping service due to cluster IP" service="elk/logstash-logstash-headless" clusterIP="None"

How to reformat my kubectl get events command?

It's simply because of events != logs

Does it mean that there are no events?

No resources found in kube-system namespace error typically indicates that there are no events available in the kube-system namespace.
Try running the command kubectl get events --all - namespaces to check if there are event available in other namespaces

Events have a short lifetime by default (I think 1 hour or something like that? Can be personalized by setting flag to apiserver) so it's possible that there are no events in the last hour for that namespace.

No resources found in kube-system namespace error typically indicates that there are no events available in the kube-system namespace.
Events seem to be retained only for a certain amount of time, so maybe there are no events in the particular namespace.
Run the command kubectl get events --all - namespaces  to check if there are event available in other namespaces
Refer to this link on Timeline of kubernetes events.
